# $2\sin2\theta=\cos\theta$ from $0^\circ$ to $360^\circ$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Right, I took two different approaches and I don't get all of the correct answers from the second approach. I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with the second approach, a friend suggested that dividing by cos may not be correct way to do it as cos could be zero.

[image: Working out]

Comment: Yes, your friend is correct, and the first computation is the systematic way to avoid that pitfall.

Comment: Your friend is right. If you know that $ab=ac$, you can only conclude that $b=c$ is $a\neq 0$. $ab=ac$ is true if $b=c$ OR if $a=0$, you must consider both options.

Comment: The test of what is right is what satisfies the original equation. When $\cos(\theta)=0$ it is easy to show that the original equation is satisfied, so this must be a solution - and a method which does not find it has gone wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the fact that $ab = 0 \implies (a = 0)\vee(b = 0)$.  You divide by $b$ and you lose the $b = 0$ predicate.  The first calculation is correct; the second suffers from the problem I have described.

Comment: Ok, it makes more sense now. In general, why is dividing both sides by a trig function (sin, cos, tan) generally allowed if they can have value of zero and you can't divide by zero